# Draw (or approximate) Poisson variable using other distributions

Tags: poisson-distribution, bootstrap-sampling

I'm experimenting with bootstrap resampling a large dataset, accessible via Trino SQL. [One approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Poisson_bootstrap) for resampling efficiently is drawing a variable from the Poisson distribution that gives how many times that row would be selected in a sampling with replacement.

Unfortunately, Trino [doesn't provide](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#cumulative-distribution-functions) a Poisson pdf function, only uniform (`random()`), normal and beta. The methods presented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Random_variate_generation) for variate generation depend on while-loops, which are awkward to compute in SQL. Writing a custom function is possible, but **is there a way to draw a Poisson variate using uniform, normal and/or beta distributions**?

Answer (score 1):

If $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ form a sequence of independent uniform random variables in $[0,1]$, then the process $(N_t)_{t \ge 0}$ defined by $N_t = \max\{n \ge 0 : U_1 \ldots U_n > e^{-t}\} = \min\{n \ge 1 : U_1 \ldots U_n \le e^{-t}\}-1$ is a Poisson process. In particular, $N_t$ has distribution Poisson($t$).

Comment: Thanks, but this is the the same algorithm I've linked in my question, proposed by Knuth, that requires while-loops. Implementing it in SQL should be possible, but also very awkward.

Comment: Questions with a lot of links to watch are impractical for the readers.